# css grid dynamic auto fill based on childs content width

Tags: css, css-grid, styled-components

Is it possible to have a CSS grid with dynamic widths based on the child content width?

I think the answer is no, but I was just checking.

I was trying this but it didn't work.

```
const Grid = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(min-content, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 1fr);
  column-gap: 10px;
  row-gap: 20px;
`;
```

Comment: Grid columns can be sized as `auto`, but you can’t combine that with `auto-fill` or `auto-fit`.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#g{
padding: 3px;
display: inline-grid; /* surprise :) */
border: 3px solid red;
grid-template-rows: 1fr;
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
b{
border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<input type='range' min='0' max='100'
    oninput='document.getElementById("r").style="width: " + this.value + "px;";'>

<div id='g'>
<b>1</b>
<b id='r'>1</b>
</div>
<img src='#' alt='some content'>
<hr>
```